# Como fazer uma função SE no SQL entre duas colunas

Tags: sql

Tenho o seguinte código, filtrei TAL.TIPO_PEDIDO sendo (000008,000061), mas preciso que quando for 000061, o código entenda que o almoxarifado será o 47, diferente do que está trazendo no ALM.ALMOXARIFADO, se for TAL.TIPO_PEDIDO = 000008, ai sim ele traz ALM.ALMOXARIFADO.

```
SELECT TAL.nome_cliente,
       TAL.data_entrega,
       TAL.referencia,
       TAL.desc_combi,
       TAL.talao,
       TAL.sld,
       TAL.elab,
       TAL.disp,
       TAL.emp
FROM   pcm_pedido_item PEDI,
       talao_tudo TAL,
       pcm_almoxarifado ALM
WHERE  PEDI.pedido = TAL.pedido
       AND TAL.item = PEDI.item
       AND ALM.almoxarifado = TAL.almoxarifado
       AND TAL.tipo_pedido IN ( 000008, 000061 )
       AND PEDI.situacao_comercial NOT IN ( 2, 6 )
       AND TAL.disp > 0
       AND TAL.sld > 0
       AND TAL.data_cadastro >= '01/05/2021'
/*AMOXARIFADO*/
ORDER  BY TAL.data_entrega
```

Comment: Seria tipo um Se( TAL.TIPO_PEDIDO=000061; ALM.ALMOXARIFADO=47), senão segue trazendo o ALM.ALMOXARIFADO igual está.

Answer (score 0):

Pode resolver isso usando lógica boleana, basta escrever uma expressão descreva o que precisa para cada caso:

*"quando for 000061, o código entenda que o almoxarifado será o 47"*
O que seria:
`TAL.tipo_pedido = '000061' AND ALM.ALMOXARIFADO = 47`.

Agora se não for (ou `OR`) será:

`TAL.tipo_pedido = '000008' AND ALM.ALMOXARIFADO = TAL.almoxarifado`

Agora basta combinar isso no `WHERE` usando `()` para separar cada expressão:

```
WHERE .....
  AND ( 
        (TAL.tipo_pedido = '000061' AND ALM.ALMOXARIFADO = 47) 
       OR
        (TAL.tipo_pedido = '000008' AND ALM.ALMOXARIFADO = TAL.almoxarifado)
      )
```

Claro, remova a linha `AND ALM.almoxarifado = TAL.almoxarifado` que já está sendo feita ai nessa condição.